# Is it possible to put a comment at the beginning of a line in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Something like:

```
''' This line is imperative: ''' x = 5
```

I cannot get the interpreter to accept that.

Comment: Those are essentially two statements. Why would you want to do such a ghastly thing, anyway?

Comment: No, you can't; that's why the interpreter won't accept it. You'd have to put a semicolon after the multiline string, to allow the two statements in one line, or (more conventional) put a `# comment` either on the line before or at the end of the line.

Comment: Did you try running it?

Comment: Even if you could, comments should be used very sparingly, and should describe *why* the particular piece of code is important or 'odd', not that it is. The code itself in almost all cases except rare circumstances should document itself.

Comment: @zwer: I am running an automated script which converts from C to Python. Now, in C, such "ghastly thing" is allowed, and I would like to handle it as is (i.e., without twisting the output).

Comment: @goodvibration Your title says "Is it possible to put a comment at the beginning of a line in python?" And I answered your question by saying, no, it isn't...

Comment: That's as if you were doing a Python -> C converter and complaining why can't you simply generate your array in C as `[x for x in range(10)]` - all of that syntax sugar is available in C, too, but without pre-processing you ain't gonna get that to compile. Those are two different languages and they cannot be structurally copied all the time. Also, while possible, that construction is heavily frowned upon in the C world as well. Finally, `'''whatever'''` is, technically, a non-breaking string, not a comment - just because there is no assignment so it's thrown away doesn't mean it's a comment.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ: No, you didn't. You answered "it isn't possible the way you've tried it" (easily concluded from your comments above).

Comment: @zwer: So you're "mad at the question" because the more strategic purpose behind it is irrelevant in your opinion. Any chance you could answer the question regardless of this strategic purpose (I didn't list it in the question specifically because of that BTW).

Comment: @zwer: Nevermind that. Already got an answer below.

Comment: `''' This line is imperative: '''` is a string, it's not a comment. Comments in Python always begin with `#`, and they're syntactically equivalent to whitespace. Unassigned strings can be _used_ like comments (and in certain situations they become docstrings), but that doesn't make them comments.

Comment: Personally, I tend to put my comments on the previous line of the code they're commenting. Inline comments just add visual clutter IMHO, and they can be inconvenient when you're refactoring the code. [PEP-0008](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#inline-comments) advises that inline comments be used sparingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot have exactly that. However, if there some reason why you *really* need to have a string at the beginning of a line (and note that this not a recommended style at all in Python), you can write:

```
''' This line is imperative: '''; x = 5
```

Note the `;` after the string. This works because `''' This line is imperative: '''` and `x = 5` are effectively two statements that can be concatenated in one line in Python with a semicolon.

Comment: I'd go as far as to highly recommend *against* it. Any coder that I know (myself included) will instinctively see that comment and probably overlook the assignment, expecting the line of code the comment references will follow on the next line.

Comment: @stevieb I'd 100% recommend against it, but I think the question is still valid, in its own way. Maybe there is a somewhat legit use case for it (e.g. annotating Python code lines for some code analysis tool or something like that).